# Django Add Related in Custom Form

Tags: python, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

[image: output screenshot]

I would want to have the highlighted functionality in my custom form. What steps should I take?

That is, from my Add Contact form, select a registrar if existing or add one and have the id as an input in the registrar field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0638b4e23dbabdcf7d7a6f2a2d5b95b980dece78/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L237)
You can use in the --init-- of your Custom form like this.

```
self.fields[field].widget = widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
    self.fields[field].widget,
    self.instance._meta.get_field(field).remote_field,
    admin_site
)
```